# classic asp in vb script HTML Render Error

Tags: asp-classic

ABCpdf error '80070000'

HTML render is blank.

D:\TPABENEFITS\WEB810678\REPORTS../../pages/reports/makepdf.asp, line 240
Hi, recently our website started showing this errors:

ABCpdf error '80070000'

HTML render is blank.

/admin/trucks_printpdfpayments_pdf.asp, line 12

i looked up the error to see what would need to be done to fix it, please note i have no idea how asp works, the original programer of this site is no longer with the company.

Here is a link to the suppourt website: http://www.websupergoo.com/support.htm#security

on 6.7 on ABCpdf it tells me i can add a line of code before (i think the line having an error)

the code would be: Doc.SetInfo 0, "HostWebBrowser", "0"

i have tried and tested it on several places on the file, though since i have no idea what the code is doing i would not really know were to place it.

on a side note, if you know of any places online to study this code let me know

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why did ABCPdf code start generating a Window Error 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015561/why-did-abcpdf-code-start-generating-a-window-error-5)

Comment: What version of ABCpdf are you using, and what version of IE is installed on your server?  I was maintaining a site on IIS6 with ABCpdf version 6 and IE8.  When we moved to IIS/IE10 it broke.  I discovered that ABCpdf actually uses IE to generate files, and older versions are incompatible with IE9 and above.  You may need to upgrade your component